# MySQL - INSERT into only if it's weekend

Tags: php, where-clause

I'm trying to populate a table from another one only if the day is a weekend, but when i try to fetch my results into a php array, it says that i'm fetching a non-object, and this error began when i added my where clause that tries to pick only weekend days. If someone could take a look and correct me, my code is:
**EDITed**

```
     $con->query("INSERT INTO eventos_dias SELECT DATE(inicio_periodo),'1','0','0','0' FROM eleva WHERE HOUR(inicio_periodo) BETWEEN 0 AND 6 AND WEEKDAY('inicio_periodo') BETWEEN 5 AND 6") 

$query=$con->query("SELECT Data, Sum(0h_6h) as sum0_6,Sum(6h_12h),Sum(12h_18h),Sum(18h_24h) FROM evnetos_dias
GROUP BY Data
ORDER BY Data ASC")

while($row->$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) //this line contains the error
{
$dados0_6_fds[] = $row['sum0_6'];
}
```

Ideas are welcome too!

Comment: Please show the code that produces the error (so the fetching probably) and error messages (from your db and from php)

Comment: `WHERE` is not valid in an `INSERT` statement. Your query will fail, you'll try to call a method on a non-object, the sky will fall and civilisation as we know it will come to an end. You have been warned. Of course, you could do the test in PHP and skip the INSERT...

Comment: Just to be 100% certain, what database are you using? MySQL?

Comment: Yep. And actually, i've just found the error, it's working the way i wrote, but the function WEEKDAY doesn't need single quotes, when i've taken them off, it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `WHERE` in an INSERT query. Do your date filtering at the PHP level and simply don't run the query at all if it's the weekend:

```
if ($is_not_weekend);
  $con->query('INSERT ...');
}
```

Comment: Ok, i'll try doing it from PHP from now on, but it worked now when i took off the single quotes from WEEKDAY function. But people says that, always when possible, do what you need in mysql. :S

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO eventos_dias(put the columns in here) 
SELECT DATE(inicio_periodo),'1','0','0','0' 
FROM eleva 
WHERE HOUR(inicio_periodo) BETWEEN 0 AND 6 
AND WEEKDAY('inicio_periodo') BETWEEN 5 AND 6
```

Always a good idea to develop your queries with a suitable tool until (and possible still after) you get the hang of sql.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mention, but i had the table already created, the columns already exists, but thanks anyways.

Comment: Eh? It does not create the table, it appends records from the select.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that

```
while($row->$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

is correct? should it not be

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

and for clarification (as I can't comment on anything but my own posts) that insert statement works fine, as the where clause is for the select.

Comment: Oh, it was mistyping, it's right on the code. I found the error, it was the single quotes on the weekday function. but thanks anyway.